# SQL Select column based on Max(other column)

Tags: sql

if I have in tblCust

```
c_id       Option         Numbers
10         1              2
5          1              1
10         2              1
```

I want to return the option where Numbers is max for c_id = 10. I've tried

```
 SELECT Option, MAX(Numbers) FROM tblCust WHERE c_id = 10
```

but no luck

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If you're asking what I think you are, the best answer depends on this.

Comment: Please clarify the question -- what is the desired result from your sample input table?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specfiy a DBMS, so this is standard SQL

```
select *
from (
   select c_id, 
          option,
          max(option) over (partition by c_id) as max_opt
   from tblCust
   where c_id = 10
) t
where option = max_opt;
```

Comment: What you mean by SQL standard?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: the ANSI/ISO standard that defines the SQL language

Comment: Some links to doc, please?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: you mean apart from the obvious one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql

Comment: IMO the `OVER clause` applied to aggregate functions in early versions of `Oracle`, `PostgreSQL` and in `SQL Server 2012`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: the "over clause" is defined by the SQL standard and is called a "window function". Apart from Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQL Server (starting with 2005) this is supported by a wide range of DBMS (e.g. DB2, Firebird 3.0, Teradata, Vertica, Sybase). The full specification of the the SQL standard is not available publically because you have to pay for it.

Comment: In the `SQL Server 2005` was implemented ranking windowing functions. The aggregate windowing functions are available in `SQL Server 2012` only.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No. `max(option) over (partition by c_id)` is available in SQL-Server 2005. The additions in 2012 version were the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions. I don't have a 2005 available to test but here is a **[SQLFiddle for 2008R2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbfc5/3)**

Comment: And here is the link to the MSDN docs: [`OVER` clause (2005 version)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Just to get a balanced view, here is the link to the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html  and the corresponding SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/07a2c/1

Comment: Ok, I have refreshed my knowledge, thanks to all. Prior to the SQL Server 2012 the running aggregates (with ORDER BY clause in OVER) are not allowed.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: correct. SQL Server 2012 finally caught up regarding window functions with Oracle, DB2, Teradata and Postgres

Comment: There are many things in SQL Server that still not caught up by other RDBMS. But it is not discussion of this topic :)

Answer (score 1):

Without subquery you can sort things to get the biggest

```
SELECT  Option FROM tblCust
WHERE c_id = 10
ORDER BY Number DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT Option, Numbers
FROM tblCust
WHERE c_id = 10
ORDER BY Numbers DESC
LIMIT 1
```

output:

```
Option  Numbers
1       2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of max() over() was intended to be against Numbers, not Option

```
select *
from (
   select c_id, 
          option,
          max(numbers) over (partition by c_id) as max_numbers
   from tblCust
   where c_id = 10
) t
where numbers = max_numbers;
```

If however the data is such that you have more than one record that is equal to the max(Numbers) - and you want only one result record - then use of row_number() may be a better option.

```
select *
from (
       select c_id, 
              option,
              row_number() over (partition by c_id order by Numbers DESC, Option DESC) as rn
       from tblCust
       where c_id = 10
    ) AS t
where rn=1
;
```

note the order by within the over() here, it places highest Numbers and Option first which is then given the row_number value of 1